# PHP fopen() and is_file() not working because of htaccess restrictions

Tags: php, file, .htaccess, fopen, file-exists

I will try to explain this as well as I possibly can. I'm developing a member-driven website where members can upload files to sell them (where they own the rights to these files).

PREMISE 1: I wanted to ensure that each member's folder could not be accessed directly and could only be reached through a link from the site itself.

This link is only generated in the member's area of the person who has bought it (for downloading the file more than once...and member profiles don't allow for linking to these folders either).

So every time a member joins they are given a file into which a .htaccess is automatically created.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?domain.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

**PREMISE 2:** When a user uploads a file, the last step in the process is to make sure that file has in fact uploaded.

```
$uploadFullPath = 'http://www.domain.com/userfiles/'.$_SESSION['uniqueKey'].'/'.$_SESSION['userNumber'].'-'.$_SESSION['latestUpload'].'.'.$_SESSION['latestExt'];
 if(fopen($uploadFullPath,"r")!==0){
  // update member usages
  $query = "UPDATE memberUsage SET usageLicenses=usageLicenses+1 WHERE memberNumber=".$_SESSION['userNumber'];
  mysql_query($query) or die(reportError('Unable to increment licenses used'));
  echo 'Your file has been successfully updated. You can view your listing within <a href="/user-area/">Your Dashboard</a>';
}
else{
 echo 'There seems to have been a problem uploading your file. Please <a href="/user-area/">go back</a> and try again from your \'incomplete listings\' page. Upload Path Provided: <a href="' . $uploadFullPath .'">' . $uploadFullPath . '</a>';
}
```

For clarity the reportError() function is just a preloaded function that churns out the mysql_error() and mysql_errno() any time an error needs reporting, to save typing it each time.

Also where above I have used fopen() I have also tried to test for the file's existence using is_file() and file_exists().

**The Problem**
With the above htaccess restrictions fopen(), is_file() and file_exists() all fail to find the file, even though when the generated $uploadFullPath is clicked it works.

However if I remove the htaccess restriction the above functions work, but equally the files can be accessed directly without buying or going through the website first.

How do I get both of these conditions to run simultaneously please? I'm not sure if it's just htaccess, just my file detection method or a combination of both.

My thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Can't you just open the file using the local filesystem's path?(eg /var/www/mysite/userfiles/more/stuff/here)? That wouldn't trigger the httpd and as such not the .htaccess file. Or are your files on a remote server?

Comment: We are talking about a site on a 'live' website, not a local machine. Does that make a difference?

Comment: Not at all, it's actually easier (resource-wise) to open it directly instead of through the http://-wrapper, since you don't have to go the extra mile through your httpd. If you know the path where your files are (and have read-access on those), you can use `file_exists` and `fopen` directly on those.

Comment: Okay and then that wouldn't trigger the htaccess violation issue, from your first reply?

Comment: Yes, because htaccess if just used by the httpd.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! I'm just fixing something else, I will give this a go and see how I get on. Thank you :)

Comment: Is there a file size limit on file_exists() or will it work for files of any size?

Comment: From the [manual](http://de2.php.net/file_exists): __Note: Because PHP's integer type is signed and many platforms use 32bit integers, some filesystem functions may return unexpected results for files which are larger than 2GB.__

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If possible, just use your local filesystem instead of the `http://`-wrapper.

So, for example, if your PHP file is `/var/www/kirby/myfile.php` and your uploads are stored in (again, an example) `/var/www/kirby/useruploads/cooluserone/test.jpg` (assuming test.jpg as an uploaded file).

In this case, you could either use the relative path `file_exists("useruploads/cooluserone/test.jpg")` or the complete path `file_exists("/var/www/kirby/useruploads/cooluserone/test.jpg")`.

Both of this would return true.

You have to make sure you have read access on the folder / files though, which you probably already have.

Comment: Thanks - this does appear to be working now, using the file path without doing a http request. Thanks!